# How can i change default document upload location in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-hook

i have to change the default document upload location in liferay. i am uploading document via CMS in liferay.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default document library stores the files/folder in:  `${liferay.home}/data/document_library`
To change this you can add a property in  `portal-ext.properties`

`dl.hook.file.system.root.dir=${newPath}` and that should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

For modifying default file upload location add new key in portal.properties

> dl.store.file.system.root.dir = {new_path}